# Extract app package for installation on another device

Tags: windows, powershell, uwp

I'm currently working on a project that requires a particular Windows 10 System UWP application. The issue I'm running into is trying to have a working version of that system app as I move to each new preview build of Windows.

I've recently found a completely working version of the application on a particular Windows build and what I'd like to do is to essentially extract the app package for the working version of this system UWP application so that I can install it into Windows installs using a build version where the pre-packaged version of the app is broken.

Are there any powershell commands or techniques that might allow me to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you mean an app that came as part of the OS from Microsoft? There is no supported way to extract and redistribute it. If the app is broken on a newer build, we should get that fixed. Did you submit feedback on this?

Comment: Yes, the Mixed Reality Portal to be specific. I believe someone on my team has a contact within the group working on it that they submit feedback to.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to extract and redistribute a Windows system app that came with the operating system.

Please submit feedback via Feedback Hub or other supported channel on the app that is broken on the build you are using.